# Why my resource do not return all meta data having "with" method?

Tags: laravel, laravel-resource

In lumen 8 app I use resources and reading here
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

I try to use “with” method, as I want to add some meta data to any request and I have no
this meta data in returned data :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\Models\Page As PageModel;
use App\Http\Resources\User as UserResource;


    class Page extends JsonResource
    {
        public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'title' => $this->title,
                ...
                'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            ];
        }
    
        public function with($request)
        {
            \Log::info( '-1 unction with ::' . print_r( 1, true  ) ); // I DO NOT SEE THIS LOGGINHG line
    
            return [
                'meta' => [
                    'version'=>getAppVersion()
                ]
            ];
        }
    
    }
```

In the referenced docs resource is declared a bit different from ResourceCollection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }

    public function with($request)
    {
        return [
            'meta' => [
                'key' => 'value',
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Could it be the issue and how can fix my resource to get all meta data ?

**Updated block:**
UserCollection - that is collection https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources
my collection is Page and I use it in controller  as :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\Page as PageResource;
use Config;
use App\Http\Requests\PageRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Validator;

class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $pages = Page
            ...
            ->get();

        return $this->sendOkResponse(PageResource::collection($pages), '');

    }
```

sendOkResponse defined in Http/Controllers/Controller.php :

```
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $requestData;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $request           = request();
        $this->requestData = $request->all();
    }

    public function sendOkResponse($responseResult, $message)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data'    => $responseResult,
            'message' => $message,
        ];
        return response()->json($response, HTTP_RESPONSE_OK);
    }
```

I suppose PageResource is destroyed at PageController controller index method exit...

**Updated block # 2:**
After some tests I found that Resource method “with” does not work if collection is returned
and I need to use ->additional in controller like:

```
return (PageResource::collection($pages)) 
->additional([
    'meta' => [
        'version' => getAppVersion()
    ]
]);
```

But in cases when I return sinopgle element(ex store method) like

```
return (new PageResource($page));
```

method “with” works ok.

That exludes using of wrapper like sendOkResponse.
Is is the only proper way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where and how are you instantiating this UserCollection and what parameter is passed? Does a collection exist after instantiating?

Comment: I provided additive info in Updated block. Is it all you requested?

Comment: Yes, so you see the `\Log::info()` data in your log files? Does your PageCollection contain the data **before** calling the  `sendOkResponse()`?

Comment: 1) No I do not see data by Log::info, so "with" method is not called. 2) No, as  in line       return $this->sendOkResponse(PageResource::collection($pages), '');  I use both, without any new method.  Have I to init PageResource with new somehow?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the result of `dd(PageResource::collection(Page::all()));` in your `index` function of `PageController`?

Comment: With line dd(PageResource::collection(Page::all())); I got hardly readable output with 200 code returned:
https://prnt.sc/19pdyoz

I try to use my log wrapper log function like : 
        \Log::info(  varDump(PageResource::collection(Page::all()), ' -1 PageResource::collection(Page::all())::') );
Output is huge, so link : https://pastebin.com/gbWgGR6u
Hsa it all info you need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel resources are intended to be returned directly from your controller's action method, not as part of an associative array representing JSON.

When wrapping your responses with the `sendOkResponse` method, the resource is not being returned directly from the method and thus `toArray` is being called on your resource. The `with` method on your resources is being ignored.

Try returning the resources directly from your controller's method. Use the `additional` method when constructing your resources to pass the extra attributes in the response. See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data-when-constructing-resources.

If you can control the API contracts, I'd recommend changing them to omit `success` entirely, this can be derived from the HTTP status code.

Comment: I define my class as :
class Page extends JsonResource

with command : 
php artisan make:resource PageResource

But in your link UserCollection is used, I suppose it was created with command 
php artisan make:resource User --collection

I prefer to use Resource based on JsonResource, as some requests 1 object, not collection.
Has it matter ?

Comment: Pls, look at Updated block # 2